# Issues with PySide6 running

Tags: python, pyside6

I recently installed Python on a Windows machine.

I installed PySide6 with no errors.
Reinstalling it shows that it is looking in a different install folder than my base Python install.

```
PS C:\Users\Owner\PyCharmProjects\InvestmentHunter> pip install PySide6
Requirement already satisfied: PySide6 in c:\python\lib\site-packages (6.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: shiboken6==6.5.2 in c:\users\owner\appdata\roaming\python\python311\site-packages (from PySide6) (6.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: PySide6-Essentials==6.5.2 in c:\users\owner\appdata\roaming\python\python311\site-packages (from PySide6) (6.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: PySide6-Addons==6.5.2 in c:\users\owner\appdata\roaming\python\python311\site-packages (from PySide6) (6.5.2)
```

Notice the install location.

Running a simple GUI program with PySide6 results in

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Owner\PyCharmProjects\InvestmentHunter\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from gui import app
  File "C:\Users\Owner\PyCharmProjects\InvestmentHunter\gui.py", line 1, in <module>
    from PySide6.QWidgets import QApplication, QTableWidget,QTableWidgetItem
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\PySide6\__init__.py", line 124, in <module>
    _setupQtDirectories()
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\PySide6\__init__.py", line 58, in _setupQtDirectories
    for dir in _additional_dll_directories(pyside_package_dir):
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\PySide6\__init__.py", line 27, in _additional_dll_directories
    raise ImportError(str(shiboken6) + ' does not exist')
ImportError: C:\Python\Lib\shiboken6\libshiboken does not exist
```

`pip install shiboken6`

results in

```
pip install shiboken6
Requirement already satisfied: shiboken6 in c:\users\owner\appdata\roaming\python\python311\site-packages (6.5.2)
```

My code is

```
from PySide6.QWidgets import QApplication, QTableWidget,QTableWidgetItem
from PySide6.QGui import QColor

app = QApplication()

table = QTableWidget()
table.setRowCount(2)
table.setColumnCount(3)

table.show()
```

I do not get an error from a PySide6 import but it does not detect QtWidgets so I get an error that the module is not found.
I am stumped as I have tried a reinstall, adding PATH variables, and a lot of other stuff listed on StackOverflow. Any help getting this running is appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you have python installed in two different locations.  You should remove one of them.

Comment: it was that simple! thanks